# JNA Native.setXXX() slow

Tags: java, jna

Not sure if this is the right place to ask. I noticed in YourKit (but any other profiler will do) huge contributions by Native.setShort, in my case. This sets fields in a Structure in order to fill jna library call arguments. SetShort is called some 10 levels underneath the jna lib proxy call. The actual function call to windows' kernel32.dll does not appear in the sampling at all. Neither does any Structure.read activity when returning the values.

Now, I looked at what this and the other primitive value setters do: they take the address of the argument and move sizeof( argument) bytes to the target adress by memcpy or bcopy, possibly surrounded by try/catch macros. Why is done? Why not just something like:

```
*((short*) target) = value
```

Would this be more efficient or is the try/catch important here? The surrounding PSTART/PEND macros seem to not always generate a try/catch.
This is the most recent JNA grab 4.2.0 from git.

**Update:** It looks like this was the profiler playing a practical joke on me. Today I saw the wasted time more evenly spread among other call stack levels from and to the actual native call.

My solution was to use JNA direct mapping: Add another function in my own DLL on top of the OS API, that takes primitive pointers instead of a `Structure.ByReference` to return values. Calling this function with a one-element primitive array for each return parameter took 370 ns vs 1500 ns (exluding `new Structure.ByReference()`).

So, in the end, Native.setXXX() methods really are slow, together with all the glue code around JNA method invocations. But JNA direct mapping does it. I have never tested actual JNI calls, so cannot compare timings here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On *nix systems, `PSTART`/`PEND` do a `setjmp`/`longjmp` to trap a range of memory faults (but only if `Native.setProtected(true)`).  On Windows, it uses structured exception handling (basically `try`/`catch`) to do the same thing, and is on by default.

Even when enabled, it's unlikely they would add much overhead compared to the overhead of the JNI transition itself (going from Java to C or vice versa).

Generally, passing a `Structure` to native code is not terribly efficient, since the automatic writes and reads depend heavily on reflection to copy Java fields into native memory.  In most cases, though, it doesn't really matter.

For those few cases where you find a bottleneck, you'd want to use JNA's direct mapping and restrict yourself to primitive arguments.

Comment: I am passing a pre-rolled Structure kept as ThreadLocal, ByReference. So there is little overhead on the java side. I did see lots of reflection overhead in JNA 4.1, but none in 4.2. really, the only thing resulting from the JNA call I see in the profiler is the setShort call. Could be YourKit fooling around, but VisualVM shows the same method, just without the stack trace. 

If other actitivies around a JNA call were inefficient, too, I would expect to see something in the profiler.

Comment: Look at the code for `Structure.read()` and `Structure.write()`, which are called automatically on each native call (unless auto synch is turned off).  I'm guessing you have a lot of setShort calls because the Structure has short fields.  And I wouldn't expect any operational difference between 4.1 and 4.2 in this area.

Comment: OK, direct mapping does it.